# How can I avoid the 100 sent message limit on Google Apps Script?

Tags: gmail-api

I have a Google Apps for Work account, and I built a couple of apps which connect to Gmail and send messages. The quota for sending these messages is 100 for me. Is there a way to raise the limit if I have a Google apps for Work account?

Comment: Did you have a look at [this](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22839?hl=en) page? You need to explain your problem more.

Comment: To clarify, I have a Google apps for Work account which raises sending limits. I was wondering if this would raise limits for emails sent through the API as well

Answer (score 1):

See this [post](https://www.labnol.org/internet/email/gmail-daily-limit-sending-bulk-email/2191/) and see if it will help you.

Rule #1 states that,

> You can send emails to a maximum of 500 recipients per day through the Gmail website. If you are a Google Apps for Work user, your daily limit is 10000 email recipients per day.

Regarding Quota limits for Google Apps Script, you may refer to this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas).